# Jinja2 - create a dynamic variable using value of variable as part of the key of another variable

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I am writing a jinja2 template for an Ansible role.  I have this in my *role/x/vars/main.yml*

```yaml
switches:
  - hostname: foo
    customer: abc
    abc_secret_key: myP@$$word
    xyz_secret_key: myS3cr3t
```

In my template, I want to reference the secret key based on the value of customer variable.

I can reference `abc_secret_key` by using `{{ item.abc_secret_key }}`.  That works, no problem.  However I really want to build the variable name dynamically and use the value of the "customer" variable (in the case `abc`) as part of variable name `abc_secret_key`.

This does not work.
I get

> "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute u'abc'"

but, hopefully it illustrates what I am trying to do

```
my secret key is {{ item[item.customer]['_secret_key'] }}
```

I would like it to render like this:

```
my secret key is myP@$$word
```

I have tried about 10-15 different renditions but, can not pin down the right syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you see the dict key lookup with a literal string key, you can compose a dynamic string to serve as the dict key:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: my secret key is {{ item[ item.customer ~ '_secret_key'] }}
```

Where the `~` is jinja2 syntax for string concatenation where either side is first coerced to a string, and then concatenated. You are welcome to use `+`, too, if you are certain that both sides are *already* strings (as is likely the case here, base on your cited example):

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: my secret key is {{ item[ item.customer + '_secret_key'] }}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thanks for the explanation, it really helps clear things up.